# Using Directives or Assembly Reference

Tags: c#, winforms

I added some buttons to a Form, but doubled clicked the wrong one and that took me to the code editor.

I decided to delete the generated code that resulted from clicking the wrong button. I did a rebuild and ended up getting an error:

> Error 1 'xxxxx' does not contain a definition for 'xxxxx' and no extension method 'subtraction_Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'xxxx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Double click that line in the Errors view and delete the line from the designer generated code where the Checked event handler has been set for the control.

Answer (score 4):

When you double click on `button`, it creates an event handler in designer generated code as:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

and in code editor you will see this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Now, if you remove only the handler, you will get an error. To resolve this you need to remove the event from designer generated code i.e. `this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);`

Same goes for checkboxes, textboxes and other controls as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a control on your Form. It called "subtraction". If it is a checkbox, and if you double click on it your developing program auto-generates the event-handler for Checked event.
It makes a code in your form's code (the void) and in yor designer file (the calling of the void).
I think you deleted only the void. You must go to the designer file and telete the event calling.
 It looks like:

this.subtraction.Checked += new System.EventHandler(this.subtracion_Checked);

You must delete this line.

Comment: As said by etveszprem and Ricky, I only deleted the void and the braces. but when you said " delete the event calling in Designer File", where is that stored? How do I locate it?
Thank you.

Comment: If you try to buld your solution, the Error list will show the entry.